# Retrieve images from resource folder

Tags: android, image, resources, drawable, android-resources

I have an SQL database, from the DB I will be getting name string using that I need to show the icon in List.
To do this I followed two methods, one is:

```
int id= context.getResources().getIdentifier(path + i.getIcon(),null, null);
```

I found this method is not much efficient, so I followed some other technique i.e

```
try {
            Class res = R.drawable.class;
            Field field = res.getField(i.getIcon());
            drawableId = field.getInt(null);
            holder.ContactImage.setImageResource(drawableId);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MyTag", "Failure to get drawable id.", e);
            holder.ContactImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_all_contacts_green);
        }
```

Here the problem is, some time the icon name what I get from DB will not be present in Drawable folder, in that time I feel my UI is sluggish if I try to scroll, I tried using both technique mentioned above but I found no use.

How to overcome this problem, when icon is missing first method throws NULL and the second one shows exception, but why does it take too much time in doing that?
how to prevent the sluggishness in my UI, any efficient techniques?

Comment: You shouldn't use reflection API as it is really slow. On Dalvik especially

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're trying to do.  The usual way to retrieve the ID of a drawable in the `drawable` folder is `R.drawable.id_value_of_drawable` where the file-name of the drawable is `id_value_of_drawable.extension`.

Comment: Hey @AljoshaBre even in my phone also its getting slow :(

Comment: @DeeV,i.getIcon() method will give me file name with extension

Answer (score 0):

> To do this i followed two methods, one is

I would recommend:

```
context.getResources().getIdentifier(i.getIcon(), "drawable", context.getPackageName())
```

> when icon is missing first method throws NULL and the second one shows exception

Do not ask for an icon that does not exist. Since you know, at compile time, exactly what icons do and do not exist, you are perfectly capable of not asking for icons that do not exist.

> how to prevent the sluggishness in my UI

Use [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) to find out exactly where your performance issue resides. Some will be in reflection -- whether you do it explicitly or (better) use `getIdentifier()`, there is still reflection going on. Ideally, you would cache the results of the `getIdentifier()` calls. But beyond that, Traceview will help pinpoint your difficulties.

Comment: But i know the reason why sluggishness occurs, its due to asking for missing icons in drawable folder. but just for asking the missing icons getIdentifier method makes my UI sluggish, why this so?.. why cant they improve this???

Comment: @LLL: "why this so?" -- I have no idea, as I would never use `getIdentifier()` with an invalid identifier. "why cant they improve this???" -- presumably because they have more important things to do. You are welcome to find out the root cause of the performance issue, then contribute a patch to the Android open source project that improves it.